# Hibernate query with deprecation warnings

Tags: hibernate

I tried to avoid the following Warning with the following code but I was not successful. Does anyone know why.

```
WARN org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker - [DEPRECATION] Encountered positional parameter near line 1, column 202 in HQL: [select distinct p.permission from org.imedcom.server.model.Permission as p inner join p.rolePermissions as rp inner join rp.role as r inner join r.userRoles as ur inner join ur.user as u where u.id = ? ].  Positional parameter are considered deprecated; use named parameters or JPA-style positional parameters instead.
```

```
    @Transactional
    UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {

        User user = User.findByUsername(s)
        if (!user) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException('User not found', s)
        }


        def permissions = Permission.executeQuery(
                "select distinct p.permission from Permission as p " +
                        "inner join p.rolePermissions as rp " +
                        "inner join rp.role as r " +
                        "inner join r.userRoles as ur " +
                        "inner join ur.user as u " +
                        "where u.id = ? ", user.id)

        def authorities = []
        permissions.each {
            authorities << new GrantedAuthorityImpl(it)
        }

        return new ImedComleGrailsUserDetails(user.username, user.password, user.enabled,
                !user.accountExpired, !user.passwordExpired,
                !user.accountLocked, authorities ?: NO_ROLES, user.id)
    }
```

I upgraded to hibernate 5, grails 3.0.17, spring 3.0.0.M2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what helped me solve this issue:

- Downgrading hibernate to **Hibernate 4**
- Upgraded to **Spring 3.1.2**

Hope this helps someone in the community.